# pandas returns a series instead of a dataframe while adding a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to perform a simple operation of creating a new dataframe from an existing dataframe and also trying to add a new column at the same time. However, pandas returns a series instead of a dataframe.

`controls['DESC']=cells1['CEL_DESCRIPTION']`

I get the following error for: `print(controls.info())`

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'info'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code and don't get an error:

```py
import pandas as pd

old = pd.DataFrame({'temp_c': [17.0, 25.0]},index=['Portland', 'Berkeley'])
print(old)

new = old.copy().assign(temp_f=lambda x: x.temp_c * 9 / 5 + 32)
print();print(new)

print();print(new.info())
```

output:

```
          temp_c
Portland    17.0
Berkeley    25.0


          temp_c  temp_f
Portland    17.0    62.6
Berkeley    25.0    77.0


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, Portland to Berkeley
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   temp_c  2 non-null      float64
 1   temp_f  2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
None
```

**EDITED**

On edit version I edit code for adding columns name with space like `temp c` instead of `temp_c` and `temp f` instead of `temp_f` like below:

```py
import pandas as pd

old = pd.DataFrame({'temp c': [17.0, 25.0]},index=['Portland', 'Berkeley'])
print(old)

new = old.copy().assign(**{'temp f': (lambda x: x['temp c'] * 9 / 5 + 32)})

print();print(new)

print();print(new.info())
```

output:

```
          temp c
Portland    17.0
Berkeley    25.0

          temp c  temp f
Portland    17.0    62.6
Berkeley    25.0    77.0

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 2 entries, Portland to Berkeley
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   temp c  2 non-null      float64
 1   temp f  2 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 48.0+ bytes
None
```

Comment: It worked. can you suggest how to add a column/var with a space like 'temp f' instead of temp_f

Comment: thanks, i am working on your new question

Comment: I upvoted and accepted as right answer. cna you plelase suggest how can I assign to a variable with space.. like 'temp f' instead of temp_f

Comment: @PawanTolani, I edit the code block as you request, is this your answer?

Comment: Thanks .. that is exactly what I was looking for..thanks a lot !!!

Comment: could you please tell me why sometimes the direct assigment such as this works 'controls['DESC']=cells1['CEL_DESCRIPTION']

' and sometimes not